# Missing select before call from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have two selects in the same stored procedure like

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(AVG([DC].[ContractedAmount]) , '$###,###,###,###.##') AS [AverageContractedAmount],
    FORMAT(MAX([DC].[ContractedAmount]) , '$###,###,###,###.##') AS [MaxContractedAmount],
    FORMAT(MIN([DC].[ContractedAmount]) , '$###,###,###,###.##') AS [MinContractedAmount],
    COUNT([DC].[ContractedAmount]) AS [TotalProjects]
FROM 
    [DesignCustomer] AS [DC]
INNER JOIN 
    [Design] AS [D] ON [DC].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]
INNER JOIN 
    [Task] AS [T] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [t].[DesignKey]
INNER JOIN 
    [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [PD].[DesignKey]
INNER JOIN 
    [Project] AS [P] ON [PD].[ProjectKey] = [P].[ProjectKey]
INNER JOIN 
    [Address] AS [A] ON [A].[AddressGuid] = [P].[ProjectGuid]
WHERE ...

SELECT
    CONCAT([P].[LegacyKey] , ' ' , [P].[Name]) AS [Project],
    CONCAT([D].[Name] , ' ' , [DT].[Abbreviation] , ' ' , [D].[DesignNumber]) AS [Design],
    FORMAT([DC].[ContractedAmount] , '$###,###,###,###.##') AS [Amount],
    [P].[NumberOfUnits] AS [Units]
FROM 
    [DesignCustomer] AS [DC]
INNER JOIN 
    [Design] AS [D] ON [DC].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]
INNER JOIN 
    [DesignType] AS [DT] ON [D].[DesignTypeGuid] = [DT].[DesignTypeGuid]
INNER JOIN 
    [Task] AS [T] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [t].[DesignKey]
INNER JOIN 
    [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [D].[DesignKey] = [PD].[DesignKey]
INNER JOIN 
    [Project] AS [P] ON [PD].[ProjectKey] = [P].[ProjectKey]
INNER JOIN 
    [Address] AS [A] ON [A].[AddressGuid] = [P].[ProjectGuid]
WHERE ...
```

I get in C# into Datatable as:

```
public DataTable ExeSQLEstimate(string sprocName, parameters... )
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sprocName, this.dbconn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MinWoodStories", SqlDbType.Int).Value = minWoodStories;
    //etc

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable("Table1")
        {
            Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        };

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    try
    {
        da.Fill(tbl);
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        this.HandleSQLError(e, "GetTableBySQL", sprocName);
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
    }

    return tbl;
}
```

but for some reason I only get one row (first select) instead two (one per select)

[image]

Why it returns only one row? Regards

Comment: Your code has multiple results, not multiple rows. You don't get one row per result set.

Comment: And the line "public DataTable ExeSQLEstimate,,," should be in the code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your procedure returns multiple result sets, each of which would get stored in a separate DataTable. You want to fill a DataSet instead of a DataTable. Then your DataSet will have 2 DataTables that contain the results of your procedure and you can index into the `DataSet.DataTables` property to access your data.

Here's a simple example, `p_MultipleResultsProc` returns 2 result sets such as your procedure does:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC p_MultipleResultsProc", conn))
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    da.Fill(ds);
}
```

After execution `ds` will contain 2 DataTables, each containing the different result sets from your procedure call.